# Get the sum of all values in a specific column of a ListView in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to get the sum of all the current values in column 2 of a "ListView".
I keep getting a "null value" exception for :

```
Me.ListView1.GetItemAt(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index, 2).Text)
```

and I also tried this which still threw the exception:

```
Dim X As Double = CDbl(Form1.ListView1.Items.Item(Index).SubItems(2).Text)
```

The Code block that is giving me the exception is:

```
  Public Sub getSubtotal()
     Dim Index As Integer
     Dim TotalValue As Double

     For Index = 1 To Form1.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
         Dim X As Double = CDbl(Form1.ListView1.Items.Item(Index).SubItems(2).Text)
         TotalValue = TotalValue + X
     Next

     MsgBox(TotalValue)
```

Comment: `SubItems(0)` is actually the Item.Text, so `SubItems(2)` is going to be the third "column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thing to keep in mind with the `ListView`, is that `SubItem(0)` refers to the `ListViewItem`, so `SubItem(1)` will reference the first actual subitem.  So your index of 2 is actually referring to what appears in the third "column".

You define `TotalValue` inside a Sub which makes it a local variable - it only resides there.  Assuming the Total is of some interest, the procedure should be a Function returning that value.  Also, your loop skips the first item, is a little wordy, and the existence of `Form1.` indicates you are not using explicit form references (use `Me` to reference the current form instance):

```
 ' Optional ToDo: pass a int value indicating which "column" to add up
 Public Function GetSubTotal() As Decimal

     Dim TotalValue As Decimal
     Dim tmp As Decimal

     ' arrays and collections start at index(0) not (1)
     ' OP code would skip the first item 
     For n as Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1

         ' ToDo: Not all items must have the same number of SubItems
         ' should also check SubItems Count >= 1 for each item
         ' try to get the value:
         If Decimal.TryParse(ListView1.Items(n).SubItems(1).Text, tmp) Then
              TotalValue += tmp
         End If          
     Next

     Return TotalValue
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Index As Integer
Dim TotalValue As Double

For Index = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
    TotalValue = TotalValue + ListView1.ListItems(Index).SubItems(2)
Next

 MsgBox(TotalValue)
```

Comment: It would be better if you would explain your answer, as to what change answers the question.