# ListView SUM of the price column while saving

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am working on a sales application and I added a listview and textboxes to add things to the list. The listview contains 3 columns :
Product-Price-Payment Type.

The code below, is the one to save the columns, but I need to add something

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim sfile As New SaveFileDialog
    With sfile
        .Title = "Choose your path to save the information"
        .InitialDirectory = ":\"
        .Filter = ("ONLY Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt")
    End With

    If sfile.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim Write As New IO.StreamWriter(sfile.FileName)
        Dim k As ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection = ListView1.Columns
        For Each x As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            Dim StrLn As String = ""
            For i = 0 To x.SubItems.Count - 1
                StrLn += k(i).Text + " :" + x.SubItems(i).Text + Space(30)
            Next
            Write.WriteLine(StrLn)
        Next
        Write.Close() 'Or  Write.Flush()
        MsgBox("File Saved !")


    End If
End Sub
```

I want to add, the SUM of the price column to be added to the saved .txt file when I save the columns. Help ?

1 More thing, Below the listview, i need a label to show the SUM of the price column too. It changes everytime I add a product. Thanks In Advance !

Comment: You could save yourself a great deal of trouble using a List(of T) as the datasource to a DataGridView - the control does all the work of populating the data.  The List(Of T) can then be serialized to disk (saved) all at once very easily.

Comment: I am using this because it is better imo and im using it for a reason. anw anyone can help me ? please

Comment: The problem with it is that everything is stored as Text which requires you to convert everything back and forth.  A Typed structure would retain the original type.  You already have a loop there - just add a variable to sum the value of the appropriate subitem

Comment: I am a begginer could you please help me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the sum of all values in a specific column of a ListView in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879594/get-the-sum-of-all-values-in-a-specific-column-of-a-listview-in-vb-net)  Your title doent reflect the core of the actual question: summing a subitem

Comment: Hey Plutonix, I fixed it ! thanks for your help. This can be closed